# Get data from post request with Rundeck webhook plugin

Tags: json, post, devops, webhooks, rundeck

I am trying to get data with rundeck webhook plugin, and for this i am usig curl command:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}' https://rundeck_server/api/12/webhook/QSxTDYd08dcYxKh1R5YJNOPQvmSJH2Z8#Netbox_Job
```

In rundeck webhook plugin options i add those 2 variables, 'whkpayload' to get all the json data and 'name' to get the name only (must return John in this example):

```
-whkpayload ${raw} -name ${data.name}
```

And finally i show them with those lines:

```
echo @option.whkpayload@
echo @option.name@
```

I get an empty result and i can't figure out why. Any one may help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/webhooks/run-job.html#using-the-raw-payload), you need to use an option called `whkpayload` in your job, and set it as `${raw}` in the webhook configuration.

I made an example:

1. The job definition in YAML format (with the `whkpayload` option):

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 0fcfca07-02f6-4583-a3eb-0002276bdf2d
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: age
  - name: car
  - name: name
  - name: whkpayload
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: command step
      exec: echo "name ${option.name} - age ${option.age} - car ${option.car} - payload
        ${option.whkpayload}"
    - description: inline-script step
      fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: echo "name @option.name@ - age @option.age@ - car @option.car@ - payload
        @option.whkpayload@"
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 0fcfca07-02f6-4583-a3eb-0002276bdf2d
```

2. The webhook [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjhnW.jpg).
3. The webhook calling from cURL:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"field1":"John", "field2":30, "field3":"chevy"}' http://localhost:4440/api/40/webhook/0vBZjWWrnXWvqENEdxkn0JRvjn5R63J0#MyWebhook
```

4. The [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EECFj.jpg).

Comment: Thank you @MegaDrive68k , that's work for this use case. 
However I am wondering if this method works to retrieve a list of dictionary with a random number of entries each time. for example one we will get 3 entry:
`[{"first_name": "Henry", "last_name": "Henry"}, {"first_name": "Lionel", "last_name": "Messi"}, {"first_name": "Cristianno", "last_name": "Ronaldo"}]`

Next time we will get just once:
`[{"first_name": "Henry", "last_name": "Henry"}]`

PS: i tried to get all the entry with whkpayload variable but it doen't work.

Comment: I don't think so, the best way in that case, is to iterate the curl call with a "for" sentence passing always the three options defined on the webhook.